# Using sql chunks in Rmarkdown with query parameters

Tags: r, google-bigquery, r-markdown, knitr, bigrquery

I am trying to work out if there is a way to pass parameters to the `sql` chunks connected to BigQuery in RMarkdown:

````
```{r setup}
library(bigrquery)
bq_auth(path = "access_token.json")
db <- dbConnect(
  bigquery(), 
  dataset = 'my_data', 
  project = 'my-project', 
  use_legacy_sql = FALSE
)

parameter_value = 10L
```

```{sql, echo=FALSE, connection=db, output.var="x}
SELECT @parameter_value
```

```{r}
print(x)
# I want to see 10 here.
```
````

See BigQuery parameterised query documentation here - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries

**Update 1**

Though `?parameter_value` injections seems to work fine for scalars, it does not apply to vectors, e.g.:

````
  ```{r}
  parameter_value = c(10L, 20L)
  ```

  ```{sql, echo=FALSE, connection=db, output.var="x}
    SELECT UNNEST(?parameter_value)
  ```
````

will fail with:

> Error in vapply(values, function(x) dbQuoteLiteral(conn, x), character(1)) :  values must be length 1, but FUN(X[[1](https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI/blob/master/R/interpolate.R)]) result is length 2

Event with scalars it is not using BigQuery engine to parameterise the query.

**Update 2**

I think it will not be possible to do this right now, because some of the [DBI APIs](https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI/blob/master/R/interpolate.R) are not implemented in `bigrquery` package, which I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/issues/391) for. And `knitr` package [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1867)

**Update 3**

It is now possible to use `params` argument in the sql chunks.

Comment: I don't know much about `bigquery` (nor have I experience using `sql` chunks) but is it possible that you need to pass a properly formatted string as `parameter_value`? Something like `paste(c(10, 20), collapse = ", ")` or whatever syntax SQL expects?

Comment: Thumb up this https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/issues/444 if you would like to use queries directly in the markdown

Answer (score 2):

You can use `?` to insert R variables in the sql chunck, see [using R variables in queries](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html#using-r-variables-in-queries)

````
    ```{sql connection=db,output.vars="x"}
    SELECT ?parameter_value
    ```
````

```r
print(x)
<int>
10
```

Comment: `Error in UseMethod("as_bq_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'as_bq_table' applied to an object of class "NULL"`

Comment: or `' failed x Syntax error: Unexpected "@" at [1:9] [invalidQuery]`

Comment: I have updated your answer to a version that worked for me

Comment: As I don't have a BigQuery connection, I extrapolated what works perfectly on SQL Server and though this would work because R replaces the ?parameter_value by its R value before sending the query. Is SELECT @parameter_value a valid query in BigQuery? Can you try if the DECLARE part without SELECT  throws an error?

Comment: Happy that you could adapt it! what is the final BQ syntax?

Comment: DECLARE probably has different syntax in BigQuery, but it is not needed anyway here.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you are using r chunks, right? according to [this example](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html) it is possible.

````
```{r}
library(DBI)
db = dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "sql.sqlite")
```

```{sql, connection=db}
SELECT * FROM trials
```
````

Comment: I need to do it with parameters for BigQuery https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about `bigquery`, but this works with PostgreSQL.
You need `glue::glue_sql()` to pass few parameters.
Discussed [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-multiple-r-variables-in-sql-chunk/2940/7)

````
```{r }
parameter_value <- c(10L, 20L)
parameter_value = glue::glue_sql("{parameter_value*}", .con = wcon)
```

```{sql, connection=wcon, output.var="x"}
select * from t
where t.price in (?parameter_value)
limit 10
```
````

Comment: does this work with rmarkdown sql chunks?

Comment: yes, it works. Updated answer, chunk was hidden by the interface